# How do I not redirect to a success_url in Django after I make a post using a modal form and stay on the current page?

Tags: django, forms, redirect, modal-dialog

Here is my problem, I have a model medication that has a foreignkey field drug. In the create view of medication if a certain drug is not found in the record, I would like to create it on the go. So I tried using django-bootstrap-modal-forms from PyPi which basically does what it says. However, when I make a post to create a new drug, I get redirected to the DetailView of the drug even I did not explicitly specify success_url in the DrugCreateView.

I have tried searching for probable solutions on the internet and also some similar problems people have in stackoverflow. I have not found an answer to my question so far.

I do not want this behavior. What I want is to stay in the medication create view and reload the page if necessary to update the foreignkey drug field as I have just added it in the database. I would really appreciate if you can help or at least give me a clue on how am I going to accomplish this. Please tell what other information I have to give and I will gladly provide it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and when I googled it I found a solution and it was Ajax.
you can use ajax to post/get data with out refreshing the page.
here some advantage and disadvantages of Ajax:
**Advantage**  :

- Improved User Experience
- Enhanced User Productivity
- Reduced Bandwidth Usage and Increased speed
- Increased Compatibility
- Supports Asynchronous Processing
- Reduced server hits and network load
- Easier Navigation

**Disadvantages** :

- Browser Incompatibility
- Insecurity
- Increased load on Web Server

you can use the link below yo how work with Ajax requests in Django: [How to Work With AJAX Request With Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)